# Left Outer Join SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am attempting to left outer join between two tables.

```
select id, startdate, name, code, email from edw.dbo.starts

id     startdate        name     code        email            yearfiled
15     2/4/2018         SO       1083        sql@gmail.com      2018
17     3/4/2018         SO       1083        ssms@gmail.com     2018
19     4/4/2018         SO       1083        ssrs@gmail.com     2018
21     5/4/2018         SO       1083        ssas@gmail.com     2018
21     5/5/2017         SO       1083        who@gmail.com      2017


select customer, return_year, revenue, code from sql.dbo.paid

customer      return_year     revenue    code 
 15             2018           15.00     1083
 17             2018           25.00     1083
 21             2018           35.00     1083
 21             2017           35.00     1083



select
  month(os.startdate)    as startmonth
 ,os.name
 ,os.code
 ,coalesce(s.revenue, 0) as revenue
 ,count(os.email)        as commission
from
  edw.dbo.starts as os
left outer join
  sql.dbo.paid   as s
    on
    os.id = s.customer
      and os.yearfile = s.return_year
where
  os.yearfiled = 2018
  and os.code = '1083'
  and os.startdate is not null
group by
  month(os.startdate)
 ,os.name
 ,os.code
 ,coalesce(s.revenue, 0);

startmonth       name       code         revenue     commission
   2             SO         1083           15.00           1
   3             SO         1083           25.00           1
   4             SO         1083            0.00           1
   5             SO         1083            0.00           1
```

The issue:

`Customer` = `21` from sql.dbo.paid shows zero for the revenue in the joined query even though it had a reported $35.00 revenue in the table.

Requested:

```
  startmonth       name       code         revenue     commission
   2               SO         1083           15.00           1
   3               SO         1083           25.00           1
   4               SO         1083            0.00           1
   5               SO         1083           35.00           1
```

Comment: there is one from 2018 as well.

Comment: @OP, I don't see how you are determining that customer 21 has anything. Customer isn't in the output. I see a 0 for month 4, but that's to be expected since there is only one record for month 4 and there is no revenue corresponding to that customer (19).

Comment: that zero seems tied to record 19

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query: https://rextester.com/XKAAFH1038

Comment: Just ran it locally and works well for me. How did you get the wrong result?

Comment: In your sample data, is `5/4/2018` May 4th, or April 5th?

Comment: 5/4/2018 is May 4

Comment: Looks like `5/4/2018` should be May 4th considering other values refer to Feb, March, & April.

Comment: I get the right results when I build the same table and data on my system and execute your query. So, I don't know how you're getting 0 on that row.

Comment: just add customer ID to your query and you will see that that row is tied to customer 19. Really add ID

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one.

```
create table starts
(id int , 
startdate date , 
name varchar(10), 
code int , 
email varchar(20),
yearfiled int )
create table paid
( customer int , 
return_year int , 
revenue decimal(10,2), 
code int) 
insert into starts values 
(15,'2/4/2018','SO',1083,'sql@gmail.com',2018),
(17,'3/4/2018','SO',1083,'ssms@gmail.com',2018),
(19,'4/4/2018','SO',1083,'ssrs@gmail.com',2018),
(21,'5/4/2018','SO',1083,'ssas@gmail.com',2018),
(21,'5/5/2017','SO',1083,'who@gmail.com',2017)
insert into paid values 
(15,2018,15.00,1083),
(17,2018,25.00,1083),
(21,2018,35.00,1083),
(21,2017,35.00,1083)

select month(a.startdate)as startmonth,a.name,a.code,
case when b.revenue is null then 0 else b.revenue end as revenue,
count(a.email) as commission
from starts a 
left join paid b on a.yearfiled=b.return_year and a.id=b.customer
where a.yearfiled=2018 and a.code=1083
group by month(a.startdate),a.name,a.code,b.revenue
/*
startmonth  name       code        revenue                                 commission
----------- ---------- ----------- --------------------------------------- -----------
2           SO         1083        15.00                                   1
3           SO         1083        25.00                                   1
4           SO         1083        0.00                                    1
5           SO         1083        35.00                                   1
*/
```